# How to handle duplicates in M-M (manytomany) relations in Java's Quarkus framework?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm working on a Quarkus codebase where 'many-to-many' relation is required. I'm using hibernate's @ManyToMany annotation for this and checking duplicates in the setter function of the parent entity.

For e.g Let's assume there are two entities Fruits and Categories.

**Fruits.java**

```
package org.acme.hibernate.orm.panache;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity;
import io.quarkus.panache.common.Parameters;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Entity
@Cacheable
public class Fruit extends PanacheEntity {

  @Column(length = 40, unique = true)
  public String name;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, mappedBy = "fruits")
  public List<Category> categories;

  public Fruit () {
  }

  public Fruit (String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setCategories (List<Category> categories) {
    this.categories = categories.stream().map(category -> {
              Category category1 = Category.find("name = :name", Parameters.with("name", category.name)).firstResult();
              if (category1 != null) {
                category1.fruits.add(this);
                return category1;
              }

              return category;
            }).filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

**Category.java**

```
package org.acme.hibernate.orm.panache;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Cacheable
public class Category extends PanacheEntity {
  @Column(length = 40, unique = true)
  public String name;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
  public List<Fruit> fruits;

  public Category() {
  }

  public Category(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

When I'm trying to save fruit entity with categories, it is successfully getting saved the first time. But the second time I'm getting

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.acme.hibernate.orm.panache.Category
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Find the code for above example [here](https://github.com/dinesh-chander/-hibernate-orm-panache-manytomany-test/tree/master/src/main/java/org/acme/hibernate/orm/panache)

Comment: Well you are replacing a hibernate collection which generally is not a good idea, have you tried to add and remove from the collection instead?. I also suggest you yo check this blog post https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ which a similar example, your issue I think is not with quarkus rather than with hibernate.

Comment: I don't think that's an issue here since tags collection isn't initialized and setter method is responsible for the initialization.

Comment: you are not only mutating the incoming list of categories you are also doing a query inside the setter - that is not good. Highly not recommended.

I'm assuming you are trying to persist something that is already persisted - just don't do that. I can't see where/how you call persist thus hard to help.

But start by removing your code in the setCategories() method - if you do want to mutate the list then do it before that call or add a dedicated method like cleanupCategories() ...but yes, recommended you remove/add elements rather than reset it to a default empty List.

Comment: I'm trying to keep only unique categories in the categories table.  If a category already exists in the table I'm linking it to the new Fruit entity.

Comment: You are thinking in java terms, but hibernate does not work exactly like that. The exception you are seeing is because hibernate has detected that your category entities are entities that at some point have been deatched from the EM.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. What's the correct approach for handling a situation like this?

Comment: Use the method add and remove from the list, like in this post https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/, even if you have a list at runtime what you actually have is hibernate specific subclass, this is way replacing the collection was not good in the first place.

Comment: In this case, I'm using rest call to create Fruit along with Categories. If I have to do what is suggested in the article, I will have to persist the Fruit class first and then add the categories using Fruit.addCategory method in the service class. I don't want to go that route if there's any way to do it using hibernate annotations.